# How can I import dynamically generated code into webworker to be accessible in debugger

Tags: javascript, web-worker

In our framework, we are dynamically creating scripts. Browser generates source code, than creates  element, put code inside and inserts into DOM. Those dynamic scripts, contain //# sourceURL=... line, so it looks like it came from separate file. It is very useful for debugging those scripts.

Now we need to do this in web workers. Web workers cannot create  elements, so the solution is eval or new Function. It works, but the code is not easily accessible with debugger. Other solution is importScripts, it also works, the code is accessible from debugger, but code must be fetched from http server. It is not the way our framework works. Our framework generates code on client side. So is there way, how to import code into webworker and have it nicely accessible from debugger?

Answer (score 1):

So I finally resolved it.

```
    let code=`function test() {
        let x=1;
        x++;
        // comment
    }
    //# sourceURL=abc`;

    let blob = new Blob([code], { type: "text/javascript" });

    let url=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)

    and then pass url to worker and let him importScripts(url)
```

and as bonus I've learned, that name of web worker can be set in his constructor. So now it looks really nice in debugger.